# Change Font Color in Flash VideoTime Component

Tags: flash, components, skinning, scene7

I am trying to skin a video player for Adobe Scene7 by modifying their provided .fla template.  So far, I have succeeded in changing everything except the text in the VideoTime component.

Looking at the properties for this library item shows it is using a class that they must be hosting:  com.scene7.fl.video.VideoTime

Is there a way to simply change the font color of this component via some actionscript(3) on the time line?

Comment: If you have nothing to add, just move on.  Why vote down a question? Isn't that why people come here?

Answer (score 0):

videoTime.setStyle("textFormat", new TextFormat("_sans", 11, 0xFFFFFF, false, false, false, '', '', TextFormatAlign.LEFT, 0, 0, 0, 0));